# Do functions have to be ``independent'' when solving first-order ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I study a real-valued function $y$ that takes the form $y(t)=f(t)+g(t)$, for all $t\geq 0$, where $f$ and $g$ are unknown, non-negative and differentiable functions.
I also know that $y$ is a solution of the following ODE:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{edo}
y'(t) + ag(t)y(t)=0.
\end{equation}
Therefore I would like to say that $y(t) = y(0)\exp\left(-a\int_0^t g(s)\mathrm{d}s\right)$. My question is, since $y$ and $g$ are not independent of each other, is it correct to solve \eqref{edo} the way I did?

Comment: It is important to know what functions are given beforehand. Do you know $g(t)$ for all $t$? Or do you know $f(t)$ for all $t$? Or both? Or neither?

Comment: Both $f$ and $g$ are unknown but they are non-negative and differentiable.

Comment: I mean, is your problem like "Given an unknown function $g(t)$, find functions $f(t)$ and $y(t)$ such that $y(t)=f(t)+g(t)$ and $y'(t)+ag(t)y(t)=0$ and study the properties of $y$" or is it more like "Given an unknown function $f(t)$ find functions $g(t)$ and $y(t)$ such that $y(t)=f(t)+g(t)$ and $y'(t)+ag(t)y(t)=0$ and study the properties of $y$" or is it different still?

Comment: To be more specific, my problem is that I am given two unknown functions $f$ and $g$ and I would like to study their asymptotic behavior. Then I also know that $y=f+g$ solves (1) and that this might be useful. But ultimately I just would like to know if it is correct to write the solution of (1) as I did in this context since $y$ and $g$ are not independent.

Comment: Is the $g$ in both roles the same, as part of $y$ and as coefficient in the ODE?

Comment: Yes this is the same function $g$ indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\def\eqdef{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$$
Yes, it doesn't matter what other conditions $\ g\ $ satisfies. If $\ y\ $ is differentiable, $\ g\ $ integrable, $\ G(t)\eqdef\exp\left(a\int_\limits{\,0}^{\,t}g(s)\,ds\right)\ $, and $\ y\ $ satisfies your differential equation $(1)$, then multiplying that equation through by $\ G(t)\ $ gives
\begin{align}
0&=G(t)y'(t)+aG(t)g(t)y(t)\\
&=\frac{d\big(G(t)y(t)\big)}{dt}\ .
\end{align}
Now integrating both sides of this equation from $\ t=0\ $ to $\ t=\tau\ $, and applying the [second fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part) to the expression on its right, gives
\begin{align}
0&=\int_0^\tau\frac{d\big(G(t)y(t)\big)}{dt}\,dt\\
&=G(\tau)y(\tau)-G(0)y(0)\\
&=G(\tau)y(\tau)-y_0\ ,
\end{align}
or, in other words,
\begin{align}
y(\tau)&=y_0G(\tau)^{-1}\\&=y_0\exp\left(-a\int_\limits{\,0}^{\,\tau}g(s)\,ds\right)\ .
\end{align}

Comment: I was afraid there might be some tricky problem here, but your demonstration is convincing. Thanks!